# Can you recognize this larvae that came from a human nose? (probable nasal myiasis?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pathology, parasitology

Those larvae came at least four different times from the nose (inside - from the mucosal) of a 60 year old man from a tropical area in South America. He lives and works in a city with a tropical climate. On another occasion a living insect came out of his nose, the picture is also attached.
[image: Larvae from the nose]
[image: Larvae - size]
[image: Insect from the same nose]

Comment: Approximately how big are the larvae and (presumably adult) insect? Did he find all of these around the same time (over the span of hours/days) or were there longer intervals between them?